# Mouse not clicking Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse

After a while, it happens that Ubuntu is not responding to mouse clicks any longer. (Whichever mouse I try to use.) But mouse movement still moves the cursor.

When I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log back in, it often solves the problem.

Currently using:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

I never observed the behavior on 16.04 with that hardware. When it happens I am usually running Chrome (and sometimes Firefox), and frequently a text editor (Sublime), the terminal (and sometimes Spotify). That's about it.

EDIT: Was able to observe the behavior with only Firefox running.

I am happy to provide any details/logs that might be relevant.